# Ignores Android WebView tap before page rendered

Tags: android

1. I have a WebView showing 1.html.
2. 1.html has a link (anchor tag) to 2.html.
3. 2.html has a link to 3.html.
4. These links are at the same position (left/top) in the view.
5. You tap on the link in 1.html, and tap at the same position again before 2.html is rendered.

What you see is 3.html.
I would like to see 2.html, since the latter tap is done before you see 2.html.

I am sure both clicks are done while 1.html is rendered, but log always says the latter click  occurred after onPageFinished and onNewPicture of 2.html.

How can I ignore the latter tap event?